# Apply function for two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe.

df0

```
    a    b 
c  0.3  0.6
d  0.4  NaN
```

df1

```
   a  b
c  3  2
d  0  4
```

I have a custom function:

```
def concat(d0,d1):
    if d0 is not None and d1 is not None:
        return '%s,%s' % (d0, d1)
    return None
```

Result I expect:

```
     a      b
  c  0.3,3  0.6,2
  d  0.4,0  NaN
```

How could I apply the function for those two dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.
The idea is first to reduce your dataframes to a flat list of values. This allows you to loop over the value of the two dataframes using [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and applying your function.
Finally, you go back to original shape using numpy [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
new_vals = [concat(d0,d1) for d0, d1 in zip(df1.values.flat, df2.values.flat)]
result = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(new_vals, (2, 2)), index = ['c', 'd'], columns = ['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df0.astype(str).add(',').add(df1.astype(str))
df = df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: 'nan' in x))
print (df)
       a      b
c  0.3,3  0.6,2
d  0.4,0    NaN
```

Another solution is last replace `NaN` by conditions with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), by default `True`s are replaced to `NaN`:

```
df = df0.astype(str).add(',').add(df1.astype(str))
m = df0.isnull() | df1.isnull() 
print (m)
       a      b
c  False  False
d  False   True

df = df.mask(m)
print (df)
       a      b
c  0.3,3  0.6,2
d  0.4,0    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you it's your specific application, you can do :

```
#Concatenate the two as String
df = df0.astype(str) + "," +df1.astype(str)
#Remove the nan
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if 'nan' not in x else np.nan)
```

You'll be better performance wise than using apply

output

```
    a        b
c   0.3,3   0.6,2
d   0.4,0    NaN
```